# How to undo assigning ownership of db_datareader/db_datawriter schema?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-administration

i *meant* to assign an SQL Server login to the

- `db_datareader`
- `db_datawriter`

database ***roles***. But if a moment of sore tummy and tiredness, i accidentally give that user schema ownership of them instead:

[image]

Ignoring for the moment what it can conceptually *mean* for a user to *"own"* those two built-in schemas. And ignoring for the moment if it is even a *problem* if a user owns those two schemas (e.g. if i want to delete the users will the built-in schemas go with it).

My question is: How do i undo it?

---

i [randomly hit keys on my keyboard, and it came out](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/9c0896e1-0f63-4010-9165-d32fa314930d):

> ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[db_datareader] TO [db_datareader]<kbd>F5</kbd>

But that didn't do anything; so now it's time to consult the experts.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5057.00 (Intel X86)   Mar 25 2011 13:50:04   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
alter authorization on schema::[db_datareader] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_datareader] to [db_datareader]

alter authorization on schema::[db_datawriter] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_datawriter] to [db_datawriter]
```

Comment: Regarding your edit, only one of each pair should be necessary. `alter authorization` changes the ownership of the securable (in this case, a schema) to the given principal. So, either you want dbo to own the schemas (as they are in the databases that I checked on my side) or you want them to own themselves. The choice is mutually exclusive (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

do the following it will make your work easy:
open SQL Server as SA account click on create new query and past blow queries 
and click on execute! done.

```
alter authorization on schema::[db_datareader] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_datareader] to [db_datareader]
alter authorization on schema::[db_datawriter] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_datawriter] to [db_datawriter]
alter authorization on schema::[db_securityadmin] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_securityadmin] to [db_securityadmin]
alter authorization on schema::[db_accessadmin] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_accessadmin] to [db_accessadmin]
alter authorization on schema::[db_backupoperator] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_backupoperator] to [db_backupoperator]
alter authorization on schema::[db_ddladmin] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_ddladmin] to [db_ddladmin]
alter authorization on schema::[db_owner] to [dbo]
alter authorization on schema::[db_owner] to [db_owner]
```